# Android video streaming from self signed https

Tags: android, ssl, video

We have an android application which is used to play videos. The videos are encrypted and stored in SD cards. The application has a small web server that then decrypts the video on the fly and streams it to the Android Media Player in the app.

To improve securtiy of the stream, we use HTTPS and a self signed certificate for the application's micro server. We added a trusted root certificate to make this work but android constantly complains about the network being compromised.

I have tried but not been able to play a https stream on the android media player without a public CA signed certificate. Is there any way to make self signed certificates be accepted without the android notification stating that the network is compromised?